# JSF Need to refresh with another result Date+days

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF form with 2 dates. Start Date is required.

2 things I would need:

When the End date is filled in --> Then the Days should be calculated and filled in.
When the Days are filled in (example: 31) --> Then the End date should be filled in.
How can this be done in JSF?

[image]

You might seen the same case as me, but what I looking for **how calculate Days If Start Date Is Filled** can someone help me please

Comment: thanks @SeverityOne

Comment: Learn the basics of ajax in combination with jsf

Comment: Most primefaces components have ajax behaviours inluded. So: yes, ajax events are required to high dynamic forms. No: is not required to implemewnt by hand